# MongoDB Webhook function to save forminput in database

Tags: database, mongodb, vue.js, webhooks

I've been trying to save data from my form in my MongoDB for some time.

I also get a response from the database.

See also: [create object in mongo db api onclick sending form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67487780/create-object-in-mongo-db-api-onclick-sending-form)

Unfortunately there are not enough tutorials in my mother tongue and I don't seem to understand everything in English.

I've tried some of the documentation, but I always fail.
What is missing in my webhook function so that the form data can be stored?

```
exports = function(payload) {

   const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");

   const mycollection = mongodb.db("created_notifications").collection("dpvn_collection");


   return mycollection.find({}).limit(10).toArray();

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Webhookfunction was totally wrong.

**READ THE [DOCUMENTATION](https://docs.mongodb.com/) FIRST**

---

```
exports = function(payload, response) {
  const mongodb = context.services.get("mongodb-atlas");
  const requestLogs = mongodb.db("created_notifications").collection("dpvn_collection");
  requestLogs.insertOne({
    body: EJSON.parse(payload.body.text()),
    query: payload.query
  }).then(result => {
    
    
  })
};
```